# PHP. How can i check if a Switch case statement has executed?

Tags: php

Is it possible to check if a switch case statement has found a match in the case part and executed successfully, and if it doesn't, how to execute something else?

eg

```
switch($type) 
{
    case "1": {
        echo "something";
        break;
    }
    case "2": {
        echo "something else";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do an echo or die() in that case...

Comment: Yes, by seeing the result of what was executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a very simple level...

```
switch ($type) 
{
    case "1":
        // code to be executed
        echo('executed 1');
        break;
    case "2":
        // code to be executed
        echo('executed 2');
        break;
    case "3":
        // code to be executed
        echo('executed 3');
        break;
    default:
        // code to be executed if different from all other conditions;
}
```

Your syntax was incorrect also... does this help?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but this is pointless as OP question also is. If there is a switch case, then **obviously** there is a need to execute different blocks of code for different event evaluations. So you see what your program did, and you'll know.

Comment: I know but he's obviously new to it all so thought was worth the helping hand :-/

Comment: That kinda helped me realize that my question was rather stupid as I forgot about the default case. Thank you for taking your time answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `default:` branch of the switch.

It will be executed if no match has been found in the `case`s (unless you forget to `break;` somewhere).